# Compiling MRPT tutorial on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I am following the tutorial on using the MRPT libraries for C++ on Ubuntu, but I'm not getting very far. I successfully downloaded the Ubuntu binaries according to http://www.mrpt.org/MRPT_in_GNU/Linux_repositories

Now I'm following the tutorial on writing the first C++ program with MRPT from this [link](http://www.mrpt.org/Writing_applications_with_the_MRPT_C%2B%2B_Library)

I downloaded and unpacked mrpt_example1.tar.gz in a directory, but when I run with command:

```
 ccmake .
```

there is no option to generate the code. `MRPT_DIR` is already set to `/usr/share/mrpt`, the location of `MRPTConfig.cmake`, so it seems `ccmake` has found that one. I tried setting the other options like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` or `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH`, but that didn't help.

How do I tell `ccmake` to actually compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ccmake`, you could use `cmake` directly, like so:

```
cmake .
```

This will generate a `Makefile` in the current directory.

```
$ ls -1
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeLists.txt
Makefile
README.txt
test.cpp
```

You can then run `make` to compile the example program:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target mrpt_example1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mrpt_example1.dir/test.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable mrpt_example1
[100%] Built target mrpt_example1
```

Then run the example program:

```
$ ./mrpt_example1
L: (0,4,2)
R: (2.000,1.000,45.00deg)
C: (x,y,z,yaw,pitch,roll)=(0.5000,0.5000,1.5000,-90.00deg,0.00deg,-90.00deg)
R+C:(x,y,z,yaw,pitch,roll)=(2.0000,1.7071,1.5000,-45.00deg,-0.00deg,-90.00deg)
Computation in: 0.0857 us
L': (-3.03553,-0.5,0.207107)
R(+)C(+)L' = (-5.82867e-16,4,2)
Should be equal to L = (0,4,2)
|(R(+)C)-L|= 3.0834
|L-(R(+)C)|= 3.0834
```

Note that you should start by extracting a clean copy of the contents of `mrpt_example1.tar.gz`, and perform these steps in the clean copy.

---

Alternatively, you could use the version of the example project that provides a `Makefile` out-of-the-box, and does not require CMake:

https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/tree/master/doc/mrpt_example1-with-Makefile

This is covered in the following tutorial:

http://www.mrpt.org/tutorials/programming/first-steps/compiling_custom_applications_in_linux_with_a_makefile_and_pkg-config/

---

Otherwise, if you must use `ccmake`:

First, extract a clean copy of the contents of `mrpt_example1.tar.gz`.

Enter the extracted `mrpt_example1` directory and run:

```
ccmake .
```

This will present an interactive dialog with the following options:

```
Press [enter] to edit option
Press [c] to configure
Press [h] for help           Press [q] to quit without generating
Press [t] to toggle advanced mode (Currently Off)
```

Press `c` to configure. The top of the screen will now show:

```
CMAKE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY   *2.4
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                *
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX            */usr/local
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH          *
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH             *
MRPT_DIR                        */usr/share/mrpt
```

Press `c` to configure again. The following options will now be available:

```
Press [enter] to edit option
Press [c] to configure       Press [g] to generate and exit
Press [h] for help           Press [q] to quit without generating
Press [t] to toggle advanced mode (Currently Off)
```

Press `g` to generate the output files (which includes the `Makefile`) and exit.

Notice that a `Makefile` has been generated:

```
$ ls -1
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeLists.txt
Makefile
README.txt
test.cpp
```

You can run `make` to compile the example program, then run the example program once it has been compiled, as described above.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that running `cmake` from a separate build directory is usually a good idea, so as not to pollute the source directory with build files. Of course, it doesn't matter so much for a software package which you don't intend to modify.

Comment: Valid point in general, though in this particular case, the example project [ships with a `README`](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/722d6f722395b079217ff432fe943b84ff72f59f/doc/mrpt_example1/README.txt) that explicitly recommends the command `ccmake .`. The answer takes an approach of minimal deviation from the official recommendation, so as to avoid introducing potential causes of confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful answer! 

It didn't occur to me that one needs to press `c` twice when using `ccmake`. Also great to learn about the alternative route via `cmake .`.